# can play 2.x match dynamic urls like so

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I know play can match /something/{id}.  What we want is a bit more complex as I may port a prototype to play as I really like the ability for the asynchronous stuff.

We have urls like so

```
/services/<moduleA>/<moduleB>/....
```

and what I really want is a pattern like this

```
/services/{capture-all-of the modules}
```

In the existing system, there would be 10 modules, and could be 3, but the client decides how to wire modules together and the data coming back is piped through each module based on that url.  Is there any potential for doing this in the playframework?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture all URL starting with /services/ and create your own requestDispatcher (not tested) :

```
//routes
GET     /services/*toBeRouted    controllers.Dispatcher.dispatch(toBeRouted: String)

//Dispatcher object
def dispatch(toBeRouted: String) = Action { implicit request => 
    toBeRouted.split("/") match {
        case Nil => BadRequest(views.html.default.wrongModule())
        case _ => {
            ...//Route to the right controller
        }
    }
}
```

**Important:** rule for path spanning several slashes must be with asterisk not colon: `*toBeRouted`

You can go a bit further to only capture valid patterns in your routes file using [regexp](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaRouting)

Comment: Thanks @marcus for the misprint with path containing slashes, all is there: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaRouting